# NPM Package functionality on form submit - front end

Tags: javascript, frontend

So I am experimenting with NPM. I could not get it working in my own at school, but want to try again during the holidays.

Here is the backend I am working with:

```
module.exports = index.js
```

Basically goal is to have a user search domain on my search bar and return the results from functionality.

I know I need a script tag after my form on the front end, but unsure what this would look like. Any advice or direction for my own knowledge would be appreciated
Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 1):

why you export like this `module.exports = index.js`, you have to export Function or Object or ... that exist in the file and needed , for exampe `module.exports = app`

after that when you want to create a web server with node (express) you should implement and run the server on a specific port like this

```js
const PORT = 3000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

In this snippet, we listen to the server on 3000 port

Comment: Right, good point on module exports, but I had taken out the port details for the purpose of this question.

How could I get the NPM functionality on the front end?

Comment: can you more explain your Q " How could I get the NPM functionality on the front end? "
I can not understand clearly